# Multi CURL using guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have question about guzzle promises. I have following servers.

- www.a.com
- www.b.com
- www.c.com
- www.d.com

I have 4 requests for each server. I'm calling from those servers by using multi_curl(guzzle) with different method.

1. I'm making 4 promises for each server and make call on server.

   - e.g prepare 4 promises and make call on a.com and getting result then
     again prepare 4 promises for b.com etc.
2. In second method I'm preparing all promises for every server and
   make single call using guzzle/settle and getting result

   ***My concern is when i use 2nd method It take almost 3-4 seconds. when 1st method takes 2-3 seconds for getting response from those servers.***
   I refer this [document](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests) for multi curl.

Your little bit help would be appreciate. :)

Here is my 1st method some code:
[image]
[image]

2nd method code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code in question?

Comment: @PtrTon I have update my question you can see my code.

Comment: @DharmeshRakholia as you can see nobody will answer you when you place screenshots instead of code snippets :)